# Understanding proof for order of permutation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

> Theorem:The order of a permutation of a finite set written in disjoint cycle form is the least common multiple of the lengths of the cycles.

The proof for the order of permutation as extracted from Gallian is as goes

> First observe that a cycle of length n has order n. Next, suppose that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are distinct cycles of lengths m and n and let k be the least common multiple of m and n. It follows from (the theorem $a^{i}=a^{j}$) that both $\alpha^{k}=\beta^{k}$ are the identity permutation....

At this point I find myself stuck.

In particular, I failed to understand how $\alpha^{k}=\beta^{k}$ follows from the the preceding theorem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is a multiple of $m$, say $k = k_1 m$, we have
$$ \alpha^k = (\alpha^m)^{k_1} = \def\1{\mathrm{id}}\1^{k_1} = \1$$
analogously $k = k_2n$ for some $k_2 \in \mathbf Z$, hence
$$ \beta^k = (\beta^n)^{k_2} = \1^{k_2} = \1 $$
so $\alpha^k = \beta^k = \1$.

In general we have that $\alpha^i = \alpha^j$ holds iff $j-i$ is a multiple of the order of $\alpha$. That is the case here, as $m \mid k-m$ and $n \mid k-n$.